# ST_Aggr_Union failed with NO matching method exception

Tags: hive, gis, archive

I tired to combine several polygon together by using ST_Aggr_Union function. I import this function to hive from a .jar file. The code I wrote is the following:

> select st_aggr_union(st_polygon('polygon ((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1))'), st_polygon('polygon ((2 0,3 0,3 1,2 1))'));

After executing this line of code, I got the following error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Aggr_Union with (binary, binary). Possible choices: *FUNC*(binary) (state=42000,code=40000)

I sure the function is in hive.

> desc function st_aggr_union;
>
> tab_name
> st_aggr_union(ST_Geometry) - aggregate union of all geometries passed

Not sure what is going on here. Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figure out what is going on here. Since ST_Aggr_Union is a UDTF, it takes a whole column as an input, and spit out the combination of all rows in corresponding column. Therefore, the answer should be

> select ST_Aggr_Union(t.polygon) from mytable t